# does the @classmethod work together with the __init__ method in python?

Tags: python, constructor, class-method

```
from dice import D20


class Hand(list):
    def __init__(self, size=0, die_class=D20, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        for _ in range(size):
            self.append(die_class())

    @classmethod
    def roll(cls, size):
        return cls(size)

    @property
    def total(self):
        return sum(self)
```

If I use `Hand.roll`, is its `size` passed to `Hand.__init__`?

Comment: What do you mean the classes size?

Comment: like in the init, we passed the parameter size = 0, so if we use the role method and return cls(size), will a list be created for the last and append the die_class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write `Hand.roll(4)`, `cls` is `Hand` and the expression is exactly `Hand(4)`.  So the argument is passed to `__init__` just as you’d expect.

But one could write

```
class Hand1(Hand):  # convenience for one die
  def __init__(self, d=6):
    super(Hand, self).__init__(1, dice.dN(d))
```

and `Hand1.roll(20)` would pass `d=20` to `Hand1.__init__` instead.  Whether this is a bug or a feature is up to you.